# SRP not blocking EXE

Tags: windows-7, windows, security

I wanted to use SRP (Software Restriction Policies) on my Windows 7 Professional for whitelisting.
For now I have just set the default level to dissallowed no additional rules just the 2 which are there by default allowing

```
%HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRoot%
```

and

```
%HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir%
```

The strange thing is it seems to restrict the access to LNK files but not to EXE files. When i put a EXE on my Desktop I can open it. If I make LNK to the same EXE it is prevented.

Why is the EXE itself not prevented?

(EXE is in the list of designated file types)